# How to exclude fields in a SOLR query

Tags: solr, solr-query-syntax

I have a SOLR query which should fetch all the fields I store, except one field.
Say I have **20** fields, do I need to hard code the **19** fields I want to fetch in the
`&fl=[f],[f],[f],....[f]'`
Or is there a way to do something similar to
`&fl=*,![f]'`

`[f]` stands for a field name.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Unfortunately the ability to remove a field name via the query string is still an outstanding improvement request. Please see [SOLR-3191](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-3191) for more details.

Until this improvement is implemented, you will need to specify all 19 fields in the `fl` parameter. However, you could update your default `/select` requestHandler to define the 19 fields that you want to return as a default setting that would be applied to all queries unless it was overridden in the query string.

Here is a modified version of the default `/select` requestHandler from the example solrconfig.xml:

```
  <requestHandler name="/select" class="solr.SearchHandler">
    <!-- default values for query parameters can be specified, these
     will be overridden by parameters in the request
     -->
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
      <int name="rows">10</int>
      <str name="df">text</str>
      <!-- Only showing 3 fields for this example -->
      <str name="fl">field1,field2,field3</str>
    </lst>
  </requestHandler>
```

For more details about these default settings and requestHandler configuration, please refer to [RequestHandlers and SearchComponents in SolrConfig](http://docs.lucidworks.com/display/solr/RequestHandlers+and+SearchComponents+in+SolrConfig).

Comment: I wish having this functionality.

Answer (score 8):

Another option could be: fields you want to include should share a common prefix; on top of that you can use globs in your fl. So for example, assuming that prefix is tobeincluded_ you can have a fl value like

tobeincluded_*

Answer (score 3):

Another option would be using the [Document transformer ValueAugmenterFactory](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Transforming+Result+Documents#TransformingResultDocuments-[value]-ValueAugmenterFactory) to replace the actual value returned of the field by an empty string.

This should work if your requirement is simply to avoid returning the content of that field.

Below is a example replacing the content of the title field:

```
&fl=*,title:[value v=""]
```

Answer (score 1):

There is another simpler patch available that solves the simple case here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-9467 if accepted it will work like this:

```
&fl=*,[fl.rm v="title"]
```

To remove the title field.

Comment: Disclaimer: I should probably mention I wrote that patch.

Comment: let us know when/if get accepted. I am not familiar with the Lucen/SOLR architecture, but can't you publish this as a stand alone plugin that can be dropped into place?

Comment: I think it might be possible to package up the main class and use this in a request handler configuration, but to get it to show up for use in `&fl` I had to add the name to a class in solr. However, the patch applies cleanly to 6.2 branch as of yesterday so if you check that out from apache git apply and build with `ant create-package` in the solr dir that should create basically the same tarball as 6.2 RC1 with this added.

Comment: downvote?? patch never went forward because 3191 was supposedly "done and ready" (I actually plan to look at and push for 3191 soon), but it did work.